# Django DetailView vs CreateView.get()?

Tags: django

I am trying to wrap my head around a CBV thing.  `CreateView` has a `get()` method that, as far as I can tell, is supposed to return info about the model just created.  Is that better served by using a `DetailView`?

Comment: That's not at all what the CreateView get is for. It's what displays the form to edit the item.

Comment: huh, I'll go back and read that section again.  Thank you